# If I wanted to say, "There are three twos in the English language," would "twos" be the correct spelling?

Tags: grammaticality

Taken from [this question on a blog](http://edwardspoonhands.com/post/106120238705/if-i-wanted-to-say-there-are-three-twos-in-the), how would correct usage in the situation where you are talking about "to, too and two" in the english language be phrased?

Would it be along the lines of "There are three variations of *two/<strike>too/to</strike>*", or would it be correct regardless of which variation was used?

Comment: You can certainly *say* it, but, short of resorting to IPA or adding weasel-words, you can't *type* it and claim that it's "legal" spelling/syntax.

Comment: The plural of *car* is *cars*. The plural of *bird* is *birds*. The plural of *cow* is *cows*. The plural of *two* is *twos*.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

OED does use the spelling *twos*:

> A.2.d. ***two and two, two by two,*** formerly also ***by two and two***: in groups or sets of two; two at a time; by twos.

**BUT** you're not talking about the word *two*. You're talking about homophones of the word *two* — *to, too* and *two*. You can't say "There are three *twos*", because there aren't. [Well, *two* is listed as noun, adjective and adverb, so I suppose there are, but that's not relevant here.]

The best you can say is that there are three words which sound like *two*, or that there are two homophones of *two* (pick whichever variant you need for that one).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you would have to write “There are three /tu/'s.” (As there are not three twos, but a two, a too, and a to, and they only equal by their pronunciation.)

Comment: And the problem is then that there are only two twos, or rather, two /tu/s. _To_ certainly isn't pronounced the same as _too_ or _two_ in my English.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet the pronounciation of *"To"* depends on whether it is stressed or not. In ***"TO be, or NOT to be - that is the question"*** the first *"TO"* is pronounced like *"two/too"* but the second *"to"* is unstressed and the vowel is therefore changed from an /u/ to a schwa.

Comment: @steveverrill: Do you really stress the first *to* in "to be, or not to be"? I've only heard that phrase pronounced as three iambs, i.e., with the stresses on *be*, *not*, and *be*.

Comment: @ruakh It's not a perfect example, just the most obvious. You are correct that the rules of iambic pentameter mean that the first *"be"* is generally pronounced more strongly pronounced than the first *"to"* but the entire third iamb is generally weaker than the first and second: ***"TO BE, or NOT (to be)?"*** A better example of different phonemes in strong pronounciation of words that are normally prononunced weakly is *"a"* and *"the"* in *"They caught A shark, not THE shark"* near the beginning of the movie Jaws.

Comment: @steveverrill: I think a more-obvious example would be one using the preposition *to*, rather than the infinitive marker. The infinitive marker is very rarely stressed, but the preposition *to* is often stressed when contrasted with *from*. For example: "It's not allowed on the way *to* school, but on the way back *from* school it's O.K." (Incidentally, we also often use /tu/ for *to* before a vowel, e.g. "to answer", or at the end of a phrase, e.g. "Do you want to?")

Comment: Even when stressed, _to_ has a lax vowel for me, not a tense one.

Answer (score 0):

In most dialects of AmE all three are homophones. So, in direct answer to your question, the spelling would not be an issue if you were SAYING it. But if I were to WRITE about it, I would write something like this: "These three English words sound alike: to, too, and two."

Answer (score -1):

No. Specifically speaking to, too, and two will not work without making the sentence more confusing than it already is. It is nearly impossible to make that one sentence make sense with one of those words. I bet this would boggle the teachers dont you think?